# How to parse this particular date format? 2022-05-18T14:00:00+00:00/PT3H

Tags: android, date, time, timezone

I have been trying for a while, but I cannot figure out how to parse this time format in android, bonus if you can convert it to the devices actual timezone.

```
{
                    "validTime": "2022-05-18T14:00:00+00:00/PT3H",
                    "value": 5.5555555555555554
                },
                {
                    "validTime": "2022-05-18T17:00:00+00:00/PT2H",
                    "value": 5
                },
                {
                    "validTime": "2022-05-18T19:00:00+00:00/PT2H",
                    "value": 5.5555555555555554
                },
                {
                    "validTime": "2022-05-18T21:00:00+00:00/PT1H",
                    "value": 6.1111111111111107
                },
```

I tried Instant, SimpleDateFormat, DateTimeFormatter and I just cannot get it right.
Thank you for your time.

Comment: `2022-05-18T14:00:00+00:00/PT3H` is [ISO 8601 notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_intervals) for an interval starting at 2022-05-18T14:00 UTC and ending 3 hours later (so at 17:00). There is no direct support built into Java, but you can (1) split at the slash (2) parse the first part into an `OffsetDateTime` (no formatter needed) (3) parse the second part into a `Duration` (still no formatter) and (4) add the duration to the start time in order to find the end time.

Comment: [Simple sample working code.](https://ideone.com/AP5Mbh) You may use `Instant` instead of `OffsetDateTime`; depending on your Java version parsing may then happen differently.